# Where's gradle-installed library's source located?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In an android project, when you install library with gradle

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'`

Is there a way to look at the source of the library?

- edit

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Talks about the sample code is included in the sdk. How do I view this sample source?

Answer (score 0):

you can to initialize FB sdk 4.0 in sattings.gradle file

```
  include ':app', 'FacebookSdk'
```

it will load whole SDK.
but still it gives you just iml file. it just pulls everything dynamically when called. 
----------- Edit ----

I just tried rightnow,
If you are using android studio,
Just select your project explorer, as **Project**. generally its **Android**.
it that you will see whole list. 
I can see facebook folder with all of its classes.
Let me know if it works for you.
Here in my project i have initialized FB SDK 4.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the source code and the samples of Facebook Android SDK on GitHub:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples